# A python script to change the Start Date of OSIsoft PI System Data Retrieval settings in Spotfire?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, osisoft

In Spotfire OSIsoft PI Asset Framework Data Source, I have the Start Date/Time set as `*-24H`in the data retrieval prompt window.
I need a Python script to change that start date based on the document property input field named StartTime. Any help is appreciated.

[image: OSIsoft PI Data Source Config]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the custom data function instead of the GUI by going to

**Tools > Create Tag Details View**

You will have more control on how to feed your input parameters.

[image]